# Related rates and sphere problem.

Tags: calculus

The radius of a spherical balloon is 10 cm.
a) How fast is the volume of the balloon changing with respect to change in its radius?
b) If the radius of the balloon is increasing by 0.5 cm/sec, at what rate is the air being blown into the balloon when the radius is 6 cm?
c) When the volume of the balloon is 50 cubic cm, at what rate is the radius of the balloon changing?

I have the answer to a and b.  I don't understand c.

Comment: a) dV/dt = 400 pi dr/dt

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a piece of data.  The volume gives you the radius, but you need the rate of volume change as well to know how fast the radius is changing.

Comment: thank you! I was wondering if something was missing!